# pass pandas dataframe as parameter in mysql query

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe df that looks something like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'SEC1':['IBM','CSCO','MSFT','AMZN' ], 'SEC2':['GOOG', 'INTC', 'ABX', 'CREE'], 'HOUR':[10 ,10 ,15, 12], 'Size':[100 ,200 ,50 ,500],'Price':[300 ,25 ,150, 80] })

df = df[['SEC1', 'SEC2', 'HOUR', 'Size', 'Price']]
```

I have a large mysql table (name=Table-B) which I want to do a left join to with my dataframe. I've been reading the pandas documentation but its not clear to me how I can do this without first reading (via read_sql/read_table) Table-B into a dataframe. I don't want to load a massive table into pandas just to then left join to df which will return a small fraction of the rows in Table-B. Is there a way to pass the dataframe df as an object/parameter in read_sql.

If I did this in mysql the code would look something like this where Table-A is my dataframe above:

```
select * from  Table-A a
left join Table-B b
on (a.sec1 = b.sec1)
where DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 12 MONTH) <= dt
group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could load `df` into a database table, using [`df.to_sql`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html):

```
df.to_sql(tablename, engine, if_exists='replace')
```

and then perform the join in the database, and read the result into a new DataFrame using [`read_sql`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html):

```
sql = '''select * from  Table-A a
         left join Table-B b
         on (a.sec1 = b.sec1)
         where DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 12 MONTH) <= dt
         group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7'''
result = pd.read_sql(sql, engine)
```

---

For example, using SQLAlchemy:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as SA
import config

df = pd.DataFrame({'SEC1':['IBM','CSCO','MSFT','AMZN' ], 'SEC2':['GOOG', 'INTC', 'ABX', 'CREE'], 'HOUR':[10 ,10 ,15, 12], 'Size':[100 ,200 ,50 ,500],'Price':[300 ,25 ,150, 80] })
df = df[['SEC1', 'SEC2', 'HOUR', 'Size', 'Price']]

engine = SA.create_engine('mysql+oursql://{u}:{p}@{h}/{d}'.format(
    u=config.USER, p=config.PASS, h=config.HOST, d='test'))
tablename = 'Table-A'
df.to_sql(tablename, engine, if_exists='replace')

sql = '''select * from  Table-A a
         left join Table-B b
         on (a.sec1 = b.sec1)
         where DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 12 MONTH) <= dt
         group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7'''

result = pd.read_sql(sql, engine)
```

Comment: so there is no getting around having to create a table in mysql as a temporary step. If the Pandas devs are reading this post it would be nice if one can do this all within the pandas infrastructure without having to move data to sql just to re-import it back to pandas.

Comment: I don't think there is a third other option. The join must be performed either by MySQL or Pandas. MySQL works solely on tables. Pandas works solely on NDFrames. Since we want to avoid loading `Table-B` into a DataFrame, the only other option is to perform the join on the database side.

Comment: Even if Pandas were to provide a function to make it *appear* as though you could join a database table with a DataFrame, under the hood Pandas would have to move the DataFrame into a temporary database table of move a table into a DataFrame.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the detailed explanation about the nuts and bolts of how this works under the surface. I appreciate it. I have gone ahead with the implementation you suggested. It all works great.